# Special characters in Oracle NCLOB

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle10g, nclob

I'm dealing with an Oracle 10g database and the following stored procedure is provided:

```
 procedure get_synopsis (
   p_id in  my_schema.products.p_id%type,
   p_synopses out sys_refcursor);  -- cursor of - synopsis_type, synopsis_text
```

In my Java code I prepare the statement in this way:

```
String idForDb = fromIdUrlToIdDb(prodIdUrl); 
statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
statement.setString(1, idForDb );
statement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

And I get the data I need in this way:

```
String defaultSyn, nonDefSyn;

String returnedId = ((OracleCallableStatement)stm).getString(1);
try ( ResultSet synopses = ((OracleCallableStatement)stm).getCursor(2) ){ // p_synopses - cursor of: synopsis_type, synopsis_text

    while( synopses!=null && synopses.next() ){

        String type = synopses.getString(1) != null ? synopses.getString(1).toUpperCase() : null;

        if( type != null ){

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( synopses.getClob(2).getCharacterStream() );
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            if("DEFAULT".equals(type)){
                defaultSyn = sb.toString();
            }else if("NONDEFAULT".equals(type)){
                nonDefSyn = sb.toString();
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The SYNOPSIS_TEXT field is an **NCLOB** but I use a String for its content since I know for sure that it won't be longer than MAX_INTEGER.
The "**N**ational character set" used is **Unicode**.

In the JSON generated from that string I can see correctly handled characters like *comma, hypen, dash, single quote, dot, parenthesis, colon, etc* but I have problems with special characters like **left single quote mark** / U+2018 ( ‘ ’ ), that is not correctly displayed. Also I can see in the text *new line characters* ( \n ) and *quotes* ( \" ).

**Is it correct to return a text in such format to consumers or should I handle it better/differently?**